# My Computer is Plugged in but not Charging

Tags: windows-10, battery, charging

My laptop computer is plugged in but not charging.  The power supply will maintain the charge level (%), but not add to it. Removing and reinserting the battery allows the power supply to add to the % charge to 100%.

Steps performed:

- Turning the computer off and restarting it returns the computer to the Plugged in, Not Charging state.
- Removing the battery again allows one complete charge, after which the laptop would no longer charge again.
- I have used more than one power supply with the same condition.

To resolve the issue, I remove the battery, obtain a complete charge, and maintain this charge by always keeping the power supply plugged in.

What is the root of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer may have an intelligent charging system.  Some batteries are actually damaged (they life shortened) if they are never allowed to discharge, at least a little.  So the circuitry doesn't just always charge to 100% and keep it there, it will let it discharge a bit then after a certain level will charge it again. I have an MSI laptop which I leave plugged in all the time that does this, but it seems it never lets the actual level drop below 90% before it starts charging again.